# parsing aggregation output mongodb using java

Tags: mongodb, parsing

```
{
    "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017", 
    "result" : [{
         "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "529f131430044109e30fc6f9"
            }, 
        "html" : { 
            "table" : { 
                "tbody" : { 
                    "Barge" : { 
                        "Name" : "ANTVERPIA 56", 
                        "Bargeno" : 6003696, 
                        "Harbour" : "HH",
                        "Reportedpresent" : "&nbsp;", 
                        "Starting" : "06-12-2013 &nbsp;spil 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I have this as result, how can i get string value of Name. In this case ANTVERPIA 56. 
I have tried with this following code but it does not working, please help.

```
for (DBObject result1: output.results()){
    String name1 =  (String)result1.get("html.table.tbody.Barge.Name");
    System.out.println(name1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access nested objects by using "." in Java driver. You have to get DBObject for each nested json object. Following code should solve problem.

```
            for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
                DBObject htmlObj = (DBObject) result.get("html");
                DBObject tableObj = (DBObject) htmlObj.get("table");
                DBObject tbodyObj = (DBObject) tableObj.get("tbody");
                DBObject bargeObj = (DBObject) tbodyObj.get("Barge");

                String name = (String) bargeObj.get("Name");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much parvin, you really helped me. You solved my problem.