# Convert this Mongodb command to java (aggregate, remove)

Tags: java, mongodb

How can i convert this Mongodb command in java?
This command find the duplicates documents and count them, after that start to remove the duplicates with keeping one of them.

I'm using Mongodb 3.

```
var duplicates = [];
db.sitesToVisit.aggregate([
  { $match: { 
    Link: { "$ne": '' }  // discard selection criteria
  }},
  { $group: { 
    _id: { Link: "$Link"}, // can be grouped on multiple properties 
    dups: { "$addToSet": "$_id" }, 
    count: { "$sum": 1 } 
  }}, 
  { $match: { 
    count: { "$gt": 1 }    // Duplicates considered as count greater than one
  }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();      // First element skipped for deleting
    doc.dups.forEach( function(dupId){ 
        duplicates.push(dupId);   // Getting all duplicate ids
        }
    )    
})

// If you want to Check all "_id" which you are deleting else print statement not needed
printjson(duplicates);     

// Remove all duplicates in one go    
db.sitesToVisit.remove({_id:{$in:duplicates}})
```

And this java code i tried, but i get confused in foreach part and removing.

```
DBCollection links = db.getCollection("sitesToVisit");

DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("Link", new BasicDBObject("$ne", ""))); 

DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("Link", "$Link"))
.append("dups", new BasicDBObject("$addToSet", "$_id"))
.append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)));
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("count",new BasicDBObject("$gt", 1)));

AggregationOutput output = links.aggregate(match,group,sort);

output.results().forEach((s)->{
    System.out.println(s);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved! Thanks Everyone :) [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422291/parsing-aggregation-output-mongodb-using-java)